# Import Servlets from JAR with Maven

Tags: java, maven, servlets

Right now I have a Servlet project **A** (including `@WebListener`s and `@WebServlet`s) that I want to package as a JAR file **A.jar** and then include it in a different project **B**. But if I do that, the `@WebListener`s from **A.jar** don't get registered.

How can I include the JAR file, such that the servlet container picks up and calls my code from project **A**? Right now I'm including the JAR as a dependency using maven.

Both POMs were generated using the `maven-archetype-quickstart` archetype and I included **A.jar** in the POM of **B** like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>{my.groupid}</groupId>
            <artifactId>{myArtifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/home/.../A.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you make it work by hand first?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, if I copy the contents of the A.jar into the target/classes folder of project B and then run `mvn war:war`, the resulting .war file is processed as intended.

Comment: Did you declare **A** as dependency in **B**'s POM? Can you add the POMs of your projects to your question (via the _Edit_ link under the tags).

Comment: @GeroldBroser I added the dependency to the question. The rest of the POM is just the standard `maven-archetype-quickstart` archetype.

Comment: Are the groupId and artifactId like this in your POM or are these just anonymizing placeholders here? [`<scope>system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)  is deprecated. Remove that and `<systemPath>` too.

Comment: Can you make it work by hand by copying B.jar inside A.war?